# Prevent that anybody can open include file directly in his browser

Tags: php, file, include, access-rights

I have a file named `startpage.inc.php` and I want to include it but prevent, that anybody can open it in his Browser. Is it possible?

Possible:

```
<?php
include 'inc/startpage.inc.php';
?>
```

To prevent:

```
www.example.org/inc/startpage.inc.php
```

Comment: If using Apache, you can define rules in .htaccess to block public access to /inc/ and all contents, while keeping access available for scripts on the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have several options.

- Check whether a constant is defined within your file. If not, `exit;`. Define a constant in the file that includes your `startpage.inc.php`. This is how a lot of free scripts prevented unwanted inclusions.
- Don't have the script in the publicly available folder. Move it below document root so it can never be accessed directly, only when included via `include` or `require`.

Answer (score 1):

There's many ways of doing this, including `.htaccess` and `php`, i.e.:

Using PHP:

```
if(count(get_included_files()) ==1) exit("Direct access denied.");
```

---

Using `.htaccess` file

```
<FilesMatch "\.inc\.php$">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

---

Take some time to read : 
[best-5-ways-to-prevent-direct-access-to-a-php-file](http://khalil-shreateh.com/khalil.shtml/index.php/websites/websites-development/106-best-5-ways-to-prevent-direct-access-to-a-php-file.html?showall=1)

Comment: The OP can use  the `.htaccess` method.

Comment: let me rephrase, what if OP doesn't want to use .htaccess and has more than one import...

Comment: I'm using this code since 2005, sorry if I cannot recall the person.

Comment: `if(count(get_included_files()) < 1)` and nevermind, you linked to it, I didn't see that.